# "For a long time" vs "in a long time"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition is correct and what is the difference in meaning if any?

> I went to the gym, something I haven't done **for** a long time.
>
> I went to the gym, something I haven't done **in** a long time.

Comment: I think they're both valid, but *for* is probably much more common, and *in* seems to me somewhat more dialectal/informal.

Answer (score 6):

Both are grammatical. There's no difference in meaning, but, at least in the UK, ***in*** a long time could be a class marker.

Comment: [This chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=done+in+a+while%2Cdone+for+a+while&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing *done in/for a while* suggests the **in** version may be the upcoming "new kid on the block".

Comment: I don't think anyone in the US would even notice the difference, let alone make a judgment based on it.

Comment: As always, we must treat nGram charts with caution, since they are based only on the written language.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the class marker? Which class, for instance?

Comment: I have no evidence, and am prepared to be told I'm wrong, but I think it likely that in the UK 'in a long time' would be less likely to be found in working class speech than in middle class speech.

Answer (score 6):

Barrie's answer is correct for the case you used as an example. However, when referring to the future, only "for" is correct.

> "I won't be going to the gym again for a long time" ← valid
>   "I won't be going to the gym again in a long time" ← incorrect

Comment: I don't agree with your example, I think they are both OK.  My example where they are not the same: **I have been living here for a long time.**  not *in* a long time.

Answer (score 3):

We have been living here for a long time. (present perfect continuous) - It began in the past, and still lasts.

They lived in New York for a long time. (past simple) - The action began and finished in the past.

They will do it in a long time. (future simple) - It will begin and be finished a long time from now, in the future.

for a long time (present perfect (continuous)) - past - present - future

for a long time (past simple) - past

in a long time - future